# Modeling Counts With Small Observations

Tags: distributions, predictive-models, missing-data, count-data

I am new to Cross Validated SE so I am going to try and formulate my question to the best of my ability.

I have a large data set that contains $5$ different fields. The fields are

```
Gender-(Male, Female),
Age-(0,18],(18,25],(25,45], (45,65], (65,100],
Region - (Northeast, Midwest, South, West)
MSA - (MSA,Non-MSA)
Doctors Office Visits - Number of times an individual 
   visited the doctors office.
```

I am trying to make a model of the counts for each possible subset. So for example I would have the subset -

```
Age - (0,18]
Gender - Male
Region - West
MSA - Non-MSA
Doctors Office Visits - Number of times an individual 
     in this subset visited the doctors office.
```

Some of these subsets have a good number of observations in which I can model the counts. However, some of the subsets have a small number of observations `(1-3)` which really skews the counts, especially if they are high (or small).

I also want to add that there are no missing data in the Doctor Office Visits field.

So my questions are:

1. I am using a poisson distribution to model the counts. Is this an effective model? Are there other ways I should model the counts? My goal is to get a predicted number of counts for each subset.
2. For the subsets where there are small observations, what can I do to model those counts so they are not skewed? Are there methods for adding in random data and modeling on that? Or can I use observations from other subsets or possibly the whole data set? I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

Any help and comments would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is MSA  / non-MSA?